# On class creation in dom

Tags: javascript, jquery

With `DomNodeInserted` being deprecated. The only examples of `MutationObserver` I can find are showing elements being updated, not added.

What is the best way to listen for a new element of a certain class being created dynamically?

Comment: Adding a DOM Node to an Element triggers Update event for the parent right? `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by passing the correct `MutationObserverInit` to the `MutationObserver`. You have to set `subtree` to `true`, and add an `attributeFilter`: `class` (as in the class name of the domNode)

Consider the following example (based on https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/):

```
// select the target node
var target = document.getElementById('some-id');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation);
  });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: false, characterData: false, subtree: true, attributeFilter: ['class']};

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

var myElement = document.createElement('div');
myElement.innerHTML = 'foo';
target.appendChild(myElement);

//triggers the mutation observer
myElement.classList.add('bar');
```

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/7zwraaxz/3/

Answer (score -1):

May be You are asking that as soon as class is added you want to trigger an event :

```
$(document).on('click', function(){
$('#theid').addClass('classname').trigger('classChange');
});


$('#theid').on('classChange', function() {
 // do stuff
});
```

if something else please explain:

Comment: Why would you use jQuery?

Comment: @ManinderSingh I am making an ajax request, then creating a table with buttons to edit the data. I wanted to basically make another js class that, when the buttons are created,  can manipulate the buttons appearance. I wanted to basically make a hook, so the js file can be dropped into any part of the system without additional config. So i just want to be able to manipulate the buttons outside of the buttons creation

Comment: I hope i would not create mess with my suggestions with Jquery only. what i understand is : you want to add a class to the dynamically added buttons. so that you can change their appearance or make buttons listen further events ? is that?

Comment: @ManinderSingh its to change the style of the button and update an attribute